# Looking for a resource that explains the musical trope "mood" used in Ashkenazic annual laining

Tags: trop-cantillation, nusach-ashkenaz

Nusach Ashkenaz has these separate laining modes:

- Regular weekly Torah reading (Shabbat, weekday, Yom Tov, etc.)
- Special Torah reading mode for Yamim Nora'im (High Holidays)
- Haftarah
- 3 Megillot - Kohellet, Shir Hashirim, Ruth
- Esther
- Eicha

Each tune is supposed to create a "mood" / nuance appropriate for that holiday. E.g. - Eicha and Esther are in major (mainly), though Esther is for Purim which is a happy occasion and Eicha is on Tish'a B'Av which is a sad occasion. Both tropes are similar to each other, yet different from the rest. There's probably a reason or "setting" for the tune / note scales chosen for each holiday.

Is there a resource that explains the nature of the different trope moods?

Comment: Like the Mixolydian Mode?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I never heard of this mode. Can you further explain?

Comment: @DoubleAA refers to this, according to everybody's favorite non-authoritative source:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixolydian_mode

Comment: @CodeswithHammer - Hmmm ,,, I have heard of "Moloch" mode and I am familiar with the "klezmer" mode mentioned in the article. But  no, these modes are used in davening, and are not the modes used in the laining that I refer to. Anyone familiar with the sound and mode in the laining areas that I mentioned, can tell that they are different and convey a certain "mood".

Comment: Are you asking about [musical modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_mode) in the technical sense?

Comment: @DoubleAA - no, nothing technical. I don't really understand the technical jargon. I'm looking for a "reason" as to what the modes convey. E.g. - Eicha and Esther are very similar to each other but are different from the tune used for the other 3 Megillot. There is probably some reason for this.

Comment: Then you should clarify what you mean by "mode" because it's a technical musical term which you apparently are using differently

Comment: The 3 megillot used during the regalim are used in the liturgy of the chagim brought down in the Torah, Eicha and Ester are read on non-Torah holidays (if 9 b'Av is even a holiday). Qohelet and Shir HaShirim are significantly more philosophical than the rest, while Rut and Ester tell stories. Eicha is the odd one out, being a kinah, rather than a story or philosophical text. Thus, as Ester and Eicha are not read on Shalosh Regalim, they do not use the same mode, and Eicha as a kinah also uses a different trope. This is just my speculation though.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - Your explanation of the Kinnah on 9 Av is credible. Still, of course looking for the mood created by the tunes for the other items. Tough to "judge" these, because Yemenite and Parsi customs are different, so there is no universal setting. I'll have to hunt the web a bit more on this. If I locate something, I'll post IY"H after Yom Tov. You're obviously not in Frankfurt, now, otherwise you wouldn't be posting.

Comment: No, I wouldn't be. Chag Sameach!

Comment: Note the additional mode (or whatever it should be called) some congregations use for the _shiras hayam_.

Comment: Sefer Chasidim (Margolit) 302